# What are the vulnerabilities for sending text to another Client's browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I have a chat application that I am developing with SignalR.  In the chat the user sends a message, now I want to make it safe so users cant send javascript or anything like that.  What are the things I should watch out for (i.e. stripping tags)?  The chat does not go in a database, it litterly just relays the message from one user's text area to the connected other user's browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want to guard against XSS - see here https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Escaping_.28aka_Output_Encoding.29 under "Escaping (aka Output Encoding)".

Any characters entered at source should be HTML encoded when output to the target browser. This will convert sequences like `<script>` to HTML for display e.g.

```
&lt;script&gt;
```

Personally I wouldn't bother stripping tags, I believe output sanitization is is the way to go as this is safe and will allow the most freedom for users to communicate without restriction (what happens if a user wants to send someone a snippet of code and your application is stripping all the HTML tags out?).

Comment: Nice answer! I was wondering if there was anyway you could refer me to an example of output sanitization, thanks!

Comment: You don't say whether you're using WebForms or MVC? But either way look at the Server.HTMLEncode method which will do what you're after http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx ... with MVC there's a shortcut to this method that can be accessed via `<%: myString %>` (as opposed to `<%= myString %>`). Any text output to the browser should be encoded it this way.